# How do I create a build system in sublime for windows to run npm?

Tags: cmd, npm, sublimetext3

**Cmd works fine**

$ npm test

outputs:
'hello'

**Sublime build does not work**

See below:

I have currently saved my project like this:

**myproject.sublime-project**

```
{
    "folders" :
    [
        {
            "path": "C:\\projects\\myproject"
        }
    ],
    "build_systems" : [{
        "name":"npm",
        "working_dir":"${project_path}",
        "shell_cmd":"npm test",     
        "windows" : {
            "shell": true
        }       
    }]
}
```

**c:\projects\myproject\package.json**

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Demo example",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo 'hello'"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
}
```

**build type:**
I have correctly selected - 'npm' as my build in build system.

When I run build, it looks like the command is strying to load package.json from my roaming folder.

**error below:**

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "test"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! path C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\npm-debug.log
[Finished in 1.5s]
```

Comment: I have discovered that the variable - $project_path refers the location where all the projects files are saved. ie in c:\users\me\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3... Which i originally thought it would be the location of the folder in my project.

Comment: Does that mean you've solved your problem now? (i.e. you replaced `$project_path` with `$folder`?

Comment: yes. I have  changed: 
- "working_dir":"${project_path}"
to -  "working_dir":"C:\\projects\\myproject"